# Migrating from Docker Swarm: Exposing my Kubernetes service to the world (on a well-known port)

Tags: kubernetes, docker-swarm

I run a tiny (read: single-node) Docker Swarm cluster that I want to migrate to Kubernetes, and I can't figure out how to expose a Service on a specific port so that I can access it from the outside world.

In Docker Swarm, I could expose e.g. a MySQL server by specifying

```
ports:
  - '3306:3306'
```

as part of the service block in my stack configuration file, which would let me access it on `127.0.0.1:3306`.

To replicate this in Kubernetes, my first instinct was to use the `NodePort` service type and specifying

```
ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: 3306
```

in the service spec. But this is not allowed: Kubernetes tells me `provided port is not in the valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767`.

Then there is `Ingress`, which seems closely aligned with what I want to do, but [it's in beta](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#prerequisites) and is apparently geared towards HTTP services (which does not cover all my use cases). There is also the `LoadBalancer` type, but I'm not using a cloud provider with support for it and so that isn't an option for me.

This has left me a bit confused. If I want to expose a service in my Kubernetes cluster so that I can access it from the outside (e.g. from the internet at large on `some-public-ip:3306`), what is a recommended (or alternatively, beginner-friendly) way to set it up? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`NodePort` is probably the simplest approach, but you will need to pick a port in the range 30000 - 32767. That way you'd access say `some-public-ip:30306` which would map to your service's port 3306 internally.

Comment: `NodePort` is fairly straightforward, but it requires that clients know about the non-standard port number, making it much harder for e.g. database clients and web browsers to access. Perhaps I wasn't being clear in my original post, but the port range restriction was the issue that I feel makes `NodePort` unsuitable for external access.

Comment: A LoadBalancer should be able to solve this, but if you can’t use that this is pretty much your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Run ha-proxy to proxy database traffic  to mysq k8 service, Ha-proxy supports https as well as tcp traffic

Comment: This sounds promising - is ha-proxy a solution that's officially endorsed by the Kubernetes maintainers?

Comment: Haproxy+mysql combination is widely used to access the database remotely.